# UISlider in details View of Splitviewcontroller in iOS 5.1 broken

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uislider

Since iOS 5.1 the UISplitviewcontroller presents the list view, when you swipe to the right and hides it when you swipe to the left. Pretty cool. The problem is, I'm using a UISlider in my Splitviewcontroller's details view. And I can't slide it anymore! Because it always pushes the listview in.

Is there a way to disable the slider area for "swipe recognition", so it doesn't detect a swipe while sliding the slider?

Or is there any other way to solve this. I just wanted to send my update to Apple and found this bug. Please, I need your help!

Comment: Alright, I found a workaround: 
yourSplitviewController.presentsWithGesture = NO;

But I'd actually want to disable the swipe only for the UISlider ... I filed a bug report. So far there seems to be no way to do it ?!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change presentsWithGesture to NO

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

or

Modify the gestureRecognizer

Comment: You can't modify the splitview's gestureRecognizer, I asked the Apple support and they told me to file a bugreport ...

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the list view of the splitViewController would pop up when whenever I tried to use the slider. I solved that problem by setting presentWithGesture to NO in the appDelegate, like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
        splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = NO;
    }

return YES;
```

}

On rereading, your problem appears to be the reverse: you do want the splitViewController to respond to swipes, but not the slider. Since UISlider is a subclass of UIResponder, I'd say your best bet is to look there. Good chance that overriding to canPerformAction:withSender: to always return NO will solve your problem.